# Ag-grid Row selection

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

While selecting the rows of an `ag-grid` with the help of cell selection using : `this.gridOptions.rowMultiSelectWithClick = true` ;
Is it possible to access the last selected row only for computation and keep the previously selected rows state intact.

Comment: How do you know when will be your last selection, because when `this.gridOptions.rowMultiSelectWithClick = true` you can click and select any number of times.

Comment: With the help of getSelectedRows() it will have the instance of the rows selected and will keep all the rows information, I want to access the instance of the latest selected row and needs to do the computation and hence there is a requirement for the mechanism to access the last row using getSelectedRows, keeping the rest rows state intact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you have to use `onRowSelected` event for that, in which you'll get the required data as `event` argument.

```
onRowSelected(event) {
  console.log("row " + event.node.data + " selected = " + event.node.selected);
}
```

> The data: event.node.data
>   Selected or not: event.node.selected

```
<ag-grid-angular
  .....
  [rowSelection]="rowSelection"
  (rowSelected)="onRowSelected($event)"
  [rowMultiSelectWithClick]="true"
  (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)"
  ></ag-grid-angular>
```

Here is the live example: [Plunk - ag-grid rowMultiSelectWithClick](https://plnkr.co/edit/xYoblilBsDOwCZgqFbPX?p=preview)

---

**Update**

You can use `gridApi` to then get the last selected node. This will even work when you are deselecting a row.  It would give us the last row which was selected before deselecting the latest row.

```
getLastSelectedNode(){
  let rows = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
  if(rows.length > 0)
    console.log(rows[rows.length - 1]);
  else
    console.log('No rows selected');
}
```

[Updated Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/xYoblilBsDOwCZgqFbPX?p=preview)

Answer (score 4):

Adding to what Paritosh mentioned, you could listen to `rowSelected` event and maintain an array of nodes.

```html
<ag-grid-angular
   [rowSelection]="rowSelection"
   (rowSelected)="onRowSelected($event)"
   [rowMultiSelectWithClick]="true"
   (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)"></ag-grid-angular>
```

```ts
selectedNodes: RowNode[];     

onRowSelected(event) {
   if(event.node.selected) {
      this.selectedNodes.push(event.node);
   }
}

getLastItem() {
   return this.selectedNodes[this.selectedNodes.length - 1];
}
```

You can call `getLastItem()` method any time according to your requirement and get the lastly selected node.

Comment: you also need to take care of the scenario and make sure that the node is removed if a node is deselected. so this solution is not yet perfect. Also, we also have `api.getSelectedNodes()` and `api.getSelectedRows()` in `gridApi`. better to use those api to achieve this - as updated in my answer.